# Issue in dijit/dojo tree while creating folder manually

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I am trying to implement a feature in my dojo tree which will allow me to **create a folder manually under any folder of the dijit tree hierarchy**. On **right click on any folder in tree --> Add a new folder**(prompt) shows up --> **a new folder name is entered** and **clicked ok**  should create a new folder under that folder.  I tried to implement it in the below way but it is not working**(CODE 1)** for the tree structure generated. Not sure where I am making a mistake. **I also tried to create an individual module to create a folder under a tree and it is working**.**(CODE 2)** Strange fact, I have added my code as below, please suggest how can I rectify this issue.

I am also fine even if I have to use dojo 1.9.1 for additional functionality. But at the moment I am not able to get the reason for which my code isnt creating a new folder, it is only opening the folder prompt but it is not putting any items created to the store.

Comment: Where exactly is your code breaking?

Comment: Hi Desertlvy, The code is breaking while executing myFunction(store,item) defined in my code and is breaking at the point store.put(childItem, {overwrite: true});. very strange indeed It is returning "undefined" as value. I checked in IE debugger tool as well it shows the same result.It returns this as the error message "'undefined' is null or not an object" in debugger console.

Comment: What object is `undefined`? `item`? `childItem`? `store`?

Comment: Store object is undefined. I created a button"add folder" which is working upon selection of folder in tree & onclick of button it creates folder manually in tree.How can I invoke the same function used in button from my tree menuitem"Add folder"? Here is button code:<button id="ba"data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"data-dojo-id="ba"data-dojo-props="disabled: true,onClick: function (evt){idCount = idCount +1;var newItem = {};newItem.id = idCount;newItem.main = selectedItemId;store.newItem(newItem);sel.setStore(store,'',{query:{main: 0}});},label:'Add project' ">},label:'Add project' " </button>